# Android native ad admob

Tags: android, admob

I have been trying to implement Native Ads from admob.

I got some sample code from [Github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples). I tried to implement this code, and the demo code works fine. The native ads show up properly.

I then created my own Admob account and obtained an `Ad Unit ID`. The previous demo code for native ad did not work with this id, and I got an error with error code `0` although my created `Ad Unit ID` works fine for banner type ads.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Same here buddy i guess we are on the same track

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Here is the link of the class from github @kgandroid :https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/NativeExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/gms/nativeexample/MainActivity.java

Comment: Ok...I saw that HUGE code...But admob is very simple.I integrated it in 3 of my projects and it works flawlessly..I will post the code here..

Comment: code please to display ad

Comment: @kgandroid  its native ad actually not Banner ad.Admob banner ad is quite simple even i did implement it successfully.Here the link for native ad :https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native?hl=en

Comment: Oh sorry..I didn't understand that

Comment: Have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: Native Ads are in beta stage. They are not open for public yet. You can only play with it now.

Answer (score 2):

guys i have facing same issue and finally i have a solution for it hope this will you all..:)
[image]

Here in this image when you are trying to create an **AdUnitId** make sure that the **width and height** here will be same width and height in the XML file like this

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ads:adSize="360x320"
  ads:adUnitId="@string/NativeAdId">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

> One more thing you have to keep in mind that the width and height you
>   are going to make ad will be fit in your xml layout ,So for this just
>   first try It in your xml and then create an Native add for this.

Just try it and feel free to tell me if you will be facing any problem after doing this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

**XML file:**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx" />
```

The **.java class:**

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        // Add a test device to show Test Ads
        //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        //.addTestDevice("B2D638A0BEECBE3464024D83BE163E0E")
        .build();
        // Load ads into Banner Ads
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Make sure to open the commented lines:

```
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("B2D638A0BEECBE3464024D83BE163E0E")
```

**when you are in debug mode**.Clicks on real Ads in debug mode may result in **blocking of your Admob account**.You will get the **testDevice id in your logcat**,replace that with that of mine.

Define the following in your manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

and also the **permission**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and you are ready to go.

**Note:**If ads are not showing up then wait atleast for 30 mins.

Comment: I really appreciate your help man but actually m dealing with "native ad".you can have go through by this link. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Recently I stucked with the same question. Then I decided to post my solution for that to [admobadapter](https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter). Hope it will help you.

The **basic usage** could look like:

```
    ListView lvMessages;
    AdmobAdapterWrapper adapterWrapper;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initListViewItems();
    }

    /**
     * Inits an adapter with items, wrapping your adapter with a {@link AdmobAdapterWrapper} and setting the listview to this wrapper
     * FIRST OF ALL Please notice that the following code will work on a real devices but emulator!
     */
    private void initListViewItems() {
        lvMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);

        //creating your adapter, it could be a custom adapter as well
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        adapterWrapper = new AdmobAdapterWrapper(this);
        adapterWrapper.setAdapter(adapter); //wrapping your adapter with a AdmobAdapterWrapper.
        //here you can use the following string to set your custom layouts for a different types of native ads
        //adapterWrapper.setInstallAdsLayoutId(R.layout.your_installad_layout);
        //adapterWrapper.setcontentAdsLayoutId(R.layout.your_installad_layout);

        //Sets the max count of ad blocks per dataset, by default it equals to 3 (according to the Admob's policies and rules)
        adapterWrapper.setLimitOfAds(3);

        //Sets the number of your data items between ad blocks, by default it equals to 10.
        //You should set it according to the Admob's policies and rules which says not to
        //display more than one ad block at the visible part of the screen,
        // so you should choose this parameter carefully and according to your item's height and screen resolution of a target devices
        adapterWrapper.setNoOfDataBetweenAds(10);

        //It's a test admob ID. Please replace it with a real one only when you will be ready to deploy your product to the Release!
        //Otherwise your Admob account could be banned
        //String admobUnitId = getResources().getString(R.string.banner_admob_unit_id);
        //adapterWrapper.setAdmobReleaseUnitId(admobUnitId);

        lvMessages.setAdapter(adapterWrapper); // setting an AdmobAdapterWrapper to a ListView

        //preparing the collection of data
        final String sItem = "item #";
        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(100);
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
            lst.add(sItem.concat(Integer.toString(i)));

        //adding a collection of data to your adapter and rising the data set changed event
        adapter.addAll(lst);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And the **result** will look like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/master/screenshots/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif)

Comment: I have implemented the same code and set adapterWrapper.setAdmobReleaseUnitId(admobUnitId); ads are showing but on admob -> Monetize -> AdMob Network report after applying filter against admobUnitId it show Network Request 0 Matched Request 0 Impressions 0

Comment: @KNOWME please clarify do you use Advanced or Express ads?

Answer (score -1):

when i first implemented admob from my newly created admob account, it took my account 2 days to finally get the ads, so dont worry, just wait...also if your account is not newly created, then see if you added this permission or not

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I did this too but didn't work.Again i wanna mention its native ad not banner ad.I am not even sure Google has released support for native ad in admob.

Comment: OK do one thing, just for testing purposes ask your frnds who have admod account n have been using for some time. Take one of their AdMob id n see if u get ads. It's OK what type of ad it is